# iOS Core Data CloudKit sync not working on AppStore

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I've built an app where I want t sync my data between devices. I've started from the default code created by Xcode 13.4.1 when you check CloudKit with Core Data.
When I run the app from Xcode on my iPhone and iPad it all syncs as expected. However, when I use the version from the AppStore it no longer works (using the same phone and Apple ID). When I overwrite the AppStore version with the same version from Xcode the data appears again...
CloudKit console never shows any data. What am I missing?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/699366 suggests something in the entitlements, but my (dutch) Xcode doesn't seem to list it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is a little embarrassing. Typical RTFM moment.
What you need to do, is deploy the CloudKit container schema to the production environment. Once I did this everything started to work as it should!

The manual to read: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/managing_icloud_containers_with_the_cloudkit_database_app/deploying_an_icloud_container_s_schema